# How to split an Object in One to Many Table using EF Core 8?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, ef-core-8.0

It's more like a design-related question, for which I am trying to find an answer but struggling. Basically, I am trying to implement versioning in my application. I have an object named `CatalogRuleApp` and am trying to split it into two tables in the database with one to many relationships in such a way that one table (RuleApp) holds the app metadata and the second table (Revisions) holds multiple revisions (with Json State of the RuleApp).

I am using EF Core version 8 and looking forward to guidelines to setup this in DbContext class and the main issue is storing the Json State of RuleApp in the Revisions table when changes are made to the rule app. Upon retrieval, that specific revision and metadata should converge to one single object `CatalogRuleApp`.

That's a sort of challenging problem I am facing, and I am looking forward to community help in solving this situation and if there is any better alternative or suggestion.

RuleApps

| Id | Name | Created On |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SampleApp | 6/12/2023 |

Revisions

| RuleAppId | Revision | JsonSerializedState (of Rules + Entities + DataElements) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | { Json } |
| 1 | 2 | { Json } |

```cs
interface IRevision
{
    public List<RuleFolder> Rules { get; set; }
    public List<Entity> Entities { get; set; }
    public List<DataElement> DataElements { get; set; }
}

public abstract class RuleApp : Entity, IRevision
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public List<RuleFolder> Rules { get; set; }
    public List<Entity> Entities { get; set; }
    public List<DataElement> DataElements { get; set; }
}

public sealed class CatalogRuleApp : RuleApp
{
    public RevisionInfo Revision { get; set; }
    // other properties... //
}

public class RevisionInfo : Entity
{
    public int Revision { get; set; }
    public CheckIn CheckedIn { get; set; }
    public CheckOut CheckedOut { get; set; }

    public string RevisionJsonState
    {
        get => JsonConvert.SerializeObject((IRevision)RuleApp);
        set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                return;
    
            var revision = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IRevision>(value);
        
            if (RuleApp != null && revision != null)
            {
                RuleApp.Rules = revision.Rules;
                RuleApp.Entities = revision.Entities;
                RuleApp.DataElements = revision.DataElements;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class CheckIn : Entity
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public string? Comment { get; set; }
}

public class CheckOut : Entity
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public string? Comment { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Versioning and many-to-many are completely independent concepts. The `Checkin` and `Checkout` properties suggest you don't mean versioning rows, but offering *locking* similar to Sharepoint's or a document management system's locking. That is separate from versioning too

Comment: That's correct, locking will happen on any particular revision of the rule app.

Comment: In the code listing, RevisionInfo is not the desired object but introduced it to somehow solve this problem situation

Comment: The easiest way to keep consistent data is to use SQL Server's [temporal tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver16). If all entities map to temporal tables, then all constraints are maintained at all points in time. When you load objects and their relations with `AS OF some_time` you load the state all the objects had at this particular point in time. You can use `FROM .. TO` or `BETWEEN` to retrieve snapshots in a specific period too. That's not exactly the same as document versioning though.

Comment: @FurqanSafdar, I have the same issue but I use JSON column.
Did you find any solution?